# Specify a specific configuration file for java command line run

Tags: java, command-line, config

I am trying to run a java project, consisting of class files and a configuration file (containing parameter values), from the command line. With a main class X.class and a configuration file Y.nrk how do I do this?

I have searched extensively for an answer as to how to include the configuration file with no results, so apologies if this is a really basic question!

Comment: 1) open file 2) read file 3) ??? 4) profit.

Comment: almost every OP is not able to clarify his/her problem properly.

Comment: How is the program figuring out which file to read now?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to java and this forum and thought it was a reasonable question. I can run by typing java X.class, but this does not include the config.

Comment: Hi, can you specify a  bit more your question. From the written above, at least I, cannot understand what the exact question is.

Comment: Thanks. I have a java project that was written by somebody else. It comprises java files which I have compiled to class files and configuration files with .nrk ending which contain the parameters of a model described by the project. I am trying to run the project from the command prompt in windows 7, which I know should be done by running the main class file. But I don't know how to indicate the specific configuration file that I want to use. I tried "open file" with the file name and it didn't work.

Comment: I tried "start (config file name)", but this just resulted in it trying to open the file in notepad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on your last comment:
It really depends of this how the code is written. Java supports passing custom (with names defined by programmer) parameters through the command line. I have couple of assumptions on your case:

- The code is written in way it accepts the config file as a custom param with -D=
- In your main class file, most probably you do have a main method, which has an args[] array through it you can pass the parameters simply by stating them one by one.

My proposal is to look carefully at the code, see how exactly the configuration file is initialized (whether is something like `new File(System.getProperty(<some name>))`; or it is something like `new File(args[<some position>]);` in this way you can figure out which option is used.

Comment: There is a main method and a "new file(args[0])" so I think I will now be able to work out how to proceed. Thank you.